# Vision SDK only recognise faces in landscape right mode on iPad

Tags: avfoundation, ios11, apple-vision

I am trying to create an app that use the Vision SDK to track a face in real time, using the camera.

So far, it's only working when I hold the iPad in landscape right mode.

The process is the following:

```
// This  is the AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
            sequenceHandler.perform(requests, on: imageBuffer)
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to rotate the stream easily, or hint the Vision SDK the correct orientation ?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually super easy:

```
 open func perform(_ requests: [VNRequest], on image: CGImage, orientation: Int32) throws
```

Use the orientation parameter (not sure how I didn't saw it earlier.)